# Adding a line break or line-wrap in JavaScript not working as anticipated

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, word-wrap

I am using this line:

```
 userResultMapOne = "But your value of " + userInputMapOne + " \nis too high for this scenario."
```

I have tried multiple different ways of using \n to get a line break. Actually, what I really want is for the text to wrap to the next line on mobile devices, but for some weird reason, the text just goes off screen (it is being displayed in a Bootstrap modal).

What is the correct way to allow JS innerHTML DOM modifications to wrap on small devices especially in a Bootstrap modal?

*Edit - I have done more investigation, but I am still none the wiser on why one of the two outputs is correct.

Here's the two inspect outputs. The first one shows the line not wrapping, but the second one, correctly, shows the line wrapping. Can anyone see why that is?

[image: First image with incorrect wrapping]

[image: Mobile phone view of unwrapped text]

[image: Second picture showing the correct wrapping, but the HTML and JS is identical except for the ID.]

Comment: `\n` will be trimmed on HTML (at least if you are not using `<pre>`), try with `<br>`

Comment: I actually did that too... and it equally didn't work. But on a large screen, everything displays as anticipated, but on mobile devices, the code doesn't seem to wrap (though in Chrome Inspect, it does... but when I display on an actual mobile device, it does not).

Comment: Try using css property: `word-wrap: break-word`

Comment: @Knick thanks - I tried this, but it didn't work :(

Comment: Can you create a small fiddle here? Before that, try using css property `white-space: pre` on it's parent.

Comment: Sadly, I am not quite sure what a small fiddle is (yet). I will try the white-space property tho.

Comment: The HTML looks like this:
<div class="word-wrap"><span id="MapOneResultOne"></span></div>
<div class="word-wrap"><span id="MapOneResultTwo"></span></div>
<div class="word-wrap"><span id="MapOneResultThree"></span></div>

The CSS looks like this:
.word-wrap {
    white-space: pre;
}

But it still isn't working on mobile phones :( It does on "Inspect" but not on the actual phone.

Comment: Ahhh, this one does work: word-wrap: break-word; but it breaks mid word.

Answer (score 0):

instead of **\n** replace **<br>**

Comment: But wouldn't that work on all devices, I only really want to wrap on small devices. Large devices it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Your are probably using `innerHTML` to insert your string, you should use `innerText`

```js
const userInputMapOn = '[USER_VALUE]';
const userResultMapOne = "But your value of  "+ userInputMapOn + "\nis too high for this scenario";

const p1 = document.querySelector('#innerHTML');
const p2 = document.querySelector('#innerText');

p1.innerHTML = '_ With innerHTML : ' + userResultMapOne;
p2.innerText = '_ With innerText : ' + userResultMapOne;
```

```html
<p id="innerHTML"></p>
<p id="innerText"></p>
```

With [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) :

```js
const userInputMapOn = '[USER_VALUE]';
const userResultMapOne = `But your value of  ${userInputMapOn} \nis too high for this scenario`;

const p = document.querySelector('p');

p.innerText = userResultMapOne;
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Edit :

If you need to insert HTML along with the string, just replace the `\n` with `<br>` and use `innerHTML` like so :

```js
const userInputMapOn = '[USER_VALUE]';
const userResultMapOne = `But your value of  <b>${userInputMapOn}</b> \nis too high for this scenario`;

const p = document.querySelector('p');

p.innerHTML = userResultMapOne.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: I am using innerHTML I shall take a look at this. Thanks.

Comment: Edited my answer ... added a replace method, in case you need to add HTML along with your string.

Comment: I am getting something a bit weird. I can get this to work on one of my five maps, but not on all five and I can't seem to see the difference. MapOne doesn't work but MapTwo does. I am looking to see where and what I have that is different, but I can not see anything (yet).

Comment: I've added some images showing the inspect output in Firefox where I can replicate the issue.

Comment: images can't tell much ... posting the full code HTML and js can help understand your problem

Comment: Ok, I might be better to do a full new post.